# Array count throwing exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

*** -[__NSArrayM count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5edd5e0

I am Getting this type of exception and its crashing my app. The code is:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 

 if(section == 0){
 return ([billDetials count]+ 1);
 }

 int rows = ([billers count] + 1);
  return rows;
}
```

[billers count]  for this statement i am getting that exception... 
Here billers is NSMutableArray having 6 objects.  tableView consists of 2 sections.

so I should get the array count as 6 but its not happenning....

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the billers array isn't getting retained properly.  Make sure it's either a retained property, or that you're retaining it properly when you create that array.

Read and fully understand this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i

Comment: The clue is in the error message... 'message sent to deallocated instance'

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the 'billers' NSArray is being deallocated before you call the count method on it.  This could be due to autorelease or a manual release before you send the count method.

If you are initializing billers using "alloc" and "init" then you are likely releasing the object too soon.  If you are initializing it using a convenience method or with "autorelease", then the object is being garbage collected too soon (you need to retain it).

Comment: Be careful not to mix up “garbage collection” with retain/release. In Cocoa, an app that uses garbage collection does not need to use retain, release, and autorelease, and those methods do nothing. (The CF equivalents still work, as the garbage collector is not normally interested in CF objects.) Cocoa Touch apps, last I heard, can't use garbage collection. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/